# Uglify source map not working in Chrome (but works in IE11 and Firefox)

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, browserify, uglifyjs, source-maps

I have a SPA ASP.NET project that uses grunt, browserify, and uglify. When I try to view the JavaScript in the Chrome debugger, it shows the minified JavaScript and seems to ignore the map file. In IE11 and Firefox, the debugger correctly shows the unminified JavaScript. I verified that "Enable JavaScript source maps" is checked in the Chrome options.

In Chrome, the last line of the minified file is:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=bundledApp.min.js.map
```

Here is my full gruntfile:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    clean: ['dist'],
    browserify: {
        build: {
            files: {
                "dist/bundledApp.js": [
                    './Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js',
                    './Scripts/underscore.js',
                    './Scripts/backbone.js',
                    './App/App.js',
                    './App/**/*.js',
                    '!./App/**/*-spec.js'
                ]
            },
            options: {
                alias: {
                    'jquery': './Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js',
                    'underscore': './Scripts/underscore.js',
                    'backbone': './Scripts/backbone.js'
                },
                transform: ['node-underscorify']
            }
        },
        test: {
            files: {
                "dist/bundledApp.js": [
                    './Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js',
                    './Scripts/underscore.js',
                    './Scripts/backbone.js',
                    './App/App.js',
                    './App/**/*.js'
                ]
            },
            options: {
                alias: {
                    'jquery': './Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js',
                    'underscore': './Scripts/underscore.js',
                    'backbone': './Scripts/backbone.js'
                },
                transform: ['node-underscorify']
            }
        }
    },
    less: {
        debug: {
            options: {
                compress: true,
                optimization: 2
            },
            files: {
                "dist/bundledApp.css": [
                    'App/App.less',
                    'App/**/*.less'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    jasmine: {
        src: [
            'dist/bundledApp.js'
        ],
        options: {
            specs: [
                './App/**/*-spec.js'
            ],
            vendor: [
                './Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.js',
                './Scripts/underscore.js',
                './Scripts/backbone.js'
            ]
        }
    }, uglify: {
        build: {
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                sourceMapName: 'dist/bundledApp.min.js.map',
            },
            files: {
                'dist/bundledApp.min.js': ['dist/bundledApp.js']
            }
        }
    }
});

// Load Grunt plugins
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jasmine');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserify:build', 'uglify', 'less']);
grunt.registerTask('test', ['browserify:test', 'jasmine']);
};
```

Comment: Did you ever figure out where the problem is?

Comment: Any solutions to this problem yet????????